# Spring spring.jackson.time-zone=UTC doesn't work

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.4, Spring Data REST, HATEOAS, Hibernate 5.2.10Final.
I'm exposing repositories with Spring Data REST and it works fine.

My model beans extends this class:

```
@TypeDefs({ @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class), @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class) })
@EntityListeners({ AuditingEntityListener.class })
@MappedSuperclass
@Audited
public abstract class AbstractEntity extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /* "UUID" and "UID" are Oracle reserved keywords -> "sid" */
    @Column(name = "sid", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false, length = 36)
    private String sid;

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    // Trick to start version counting from 1 instead of 0
    @Version
    private long version = 1;
```

Like you see, I'm using JDK 8 LocalDateTime. In my pom.xml I'm using also:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In fact the REST reply is serialized in the right way:

```
{
    "sid": "2b2530a4-6cc7-41a0-a7b5-9bf0466223b4",
    "createdDate": "2017-06-30T19:12:44",
    "lastModifiedDate": "2017-06-30T19:12:44",
    "lastModifiedBy": null,
    "name": "Administrator",
    "landlinePhone": null,
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "username": "admin",
    "email": "admin@email.com",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Rome",
    "cashFund": 0,
    "enabled": true,
    "roles": [
      "Amministratore"
    ],
    "activeWorkSession": null,
    "new": false
  }
```

I'm storing date time in UTC format in the database thanks to these properties and it works fine:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/buslet?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = UTC
```

I want that my REST endpoints return date time in UTC but unfortunately it doesn't work.
I've to specify that my JDK is using system default locale (Europe/Rome) and I set these property that should do the trick...

```
spring.jackson.time-zone=UTC
spring.jackson.deserialization.adjust_dates_to_context_time_zone=false
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I used   com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

package from below dependency jar
try with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Annotate class property with below annotation

**@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING ,pattern = "dd-MM-YYYY" , timezone="UTC")
    private Date from_date;**